Use PCA with Python Polars
I'm trying to use PCA (from the scikit-learn library) with Polars. I'm following this Kaggle notebook, which uses Pandas, where they set an index for clustering. However, Polars doesn't have the concept of an index or multi-index.
Here’s my current approach:
pca = PCA().fit(
   customer_data_scaled.select(pl.all().exclude("CustomerID"))
)

But with this aproach im losing the CustomerID.
Also tried
pca = PCA().fit(
    X = customer_data_scaled,
    y = "CustomerID"
)

But on that way , all the info get stuck on the first cluster.
Example Data:
import polars as pl

data = {'CustomerID__CustomerID': ['12346', '12347', '12348', '12349', '12350'],
 'Days_Since_Last_Purchase__Days_Since_Last_Purchase': [2.293181358195162,
  -0.9093550023713796,
  -0.18498889715372174,
  -0.7483457675933288,
  2.1421969281293722],
 'Total_Transactions__Total_Transactions': [-0.4764575258322774,
  0.7148300598787217,
  5.750845212223408e-05,
  -0.7147150429744773,
  -0.7147150429744773],
 'Total_Spend__Total_Spend': [-0.8293123590792867,
  2.451307855177288,
  0.26466411406493745,
  0.2801233688550584,
  -0.605225449007581],
 'unique_products_purchased__unique_products_purchased': [-0.8802018492520798,
  0.7976258516484461,
  -0.5512160255460943,
  0.2876978249041687,
  -0.6334624814725907],
 'Average_Days_Between_Purchases__Average_Days_Between_Purchases': [-0.3221805403412395,
  -0.1222333928444573,
  0.7621482210836178,
  -0.3221805403412395,
  -0.3221805403412395],
 'Day_Of_Week__Day_Of_Week': [2, 2, 4, 1, 3],
 'Hour__Hour': [-1.1081405784850002,
  0.6220370799522927,
  2.7847591529989093,
  -1.5406849930943236,
  1.4871259091709395],
 'Average_Transaction_Value__Average_Transaction_Value': [-1.282393028529395,
  1.5081594527658793,
  0.34607887126665193,
  5.323543943326011,
  0.05189247073759856],
 'Is_UK__Is_UK': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'Cancellation_Frequency__Cancellation_Frequency': [0.3814774558208268,
  -0.5289264033183929,
  -0.5289264033183929,
  -0.5289264033183929,
  -0.5289264033183929],
 'Monthly_Spending_Mean__Monthly_Spending_Mean': [-1.3190523375854926,
  1.0052503065380078,
  0.03733195117007402,
  4.183154438138661,
  -0.20770132922803144],
 'Monthly_Spending_Std__Monthly_Spending_Std': [-0.7096520287471256,
  1.2975650939605592,
  0.49016569022164963,
  -0.7096520287471256,
  -0.7096520287471256],
 'Spending_Trend__Spending_Trend': [0.08062714678599057,
  0.1080562113377501,
  -0.5362051086492967,
  0.08062714678599057,
  0.08062714678599057]}

customer_data_scaled = pl.DataFrame(data)

Full code with desired output:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Apply PCA
pca = PCA().fit(X = customer_data_scaled.select(pl.all().exclude("CustomerID__CustomerID")),
                y = customer_data_scaled.select(pl.col("CustomerID__CustomerID"))
                )



# Calculate the Cumulative Sum of the Explained Variance
explained_variance_ratio = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
cumulative_explained_variance = np.cumsum(explained_variance_ratio)

# Set the optimal k value (based on our analysis, we can choose 6)
optimal_k = 6

# Set seaborn plot style
sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor': '#fcf0dc'}, style='darkgrid')

# Plot the cumulative explained variance against the number of components
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

# Bar chart for the explained variance of each component
barplot = sns.barplot(x=list(range(1, len(cumulative_explained_variance) + 1)),
                      y=explained_variance_ratio,
                      color='#fcc36d',
                      alpha=0.8)

# Line plot for the cumulative explained variance
lineplot, = plt.plot(range(0, len(cumulative_explained_variance)), cumulative_explained_variance,
                     marker='o', linestyle='--', color='#ff6200', linewidth=2)

# Plot optimal k value line
optimal_k_line = plt.axvline(optimal_k - 1, color='red', linestyle='--', label=f'Optimal k value = {optimal_k}') 

# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel('Number of Components', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Explained Variance', fontsize=14)
plt.title('Cumulative Variance vs. Number of Components', fontsize=18)

# Customize ticks and legend
plt.xticks(range(0, len(cumulative_explained_variance)))
plt.legend(handles=[barplot.patches[0], lineplot, optimal_k_line],
           labels=['Explained Variance of Each Component', 'Cumulative Explained Variance', f'Optimal k value = {optimal_k}'],
           loc=(0.62, 0.1),
           frameon=True,
           framealpha=1.0,  
           edgecolor='#ff6200')  

# Display the variance values for both graphs on the plots
x_offset = -0.3
y_offset = 0.01
for i, (ev_ratio, cum_ev_ratio) in enumerate(zip(explained_variance_ratio, cumulative_explained_variance)):
    plt.text(i, ev_ratio, f"{ev_ratio:.2f}", ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=10)
    if i > 0:
        plt.text(i + x_offset, cum_ev_ratio + y_offset, f"{cum_ev_ratio:.2f}", ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=10)

plt.grid(axis='both')   
plt.show()


What is the expected outcome here?

@Hericks I find out that maybe i need to reffer to X and U like this:
 X = customer_data_scaled.select(pl.all().exclude("CustomerID__CustomerID")),                 y = customer_data_scaled.select(pl.col("CustomerID__CustomerID"))
How can i make sure that im using the same "index"  for each PCA later?

I don't understand why you are setting y (it is ignored by PCA).

@Hericks Beucase it the ID of each record, its not a feature

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
